# XSL to HTML in .Net 1.1: How to include javascript which has '&&' without getting errors?

Tags: .net, xslt, escaping

I am transforming xml to html using xslt in .Net 1.1. One part contains a javascript section where 2 vars are ANDed (&&). The transform throws an unknown entity error. What can I do? I have tried 'CDATA' and 'disable-output-escaping' but without success.  If I write && then the output is also '&&'.

Here is my code. (trimmed for clarity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" standalone="yes" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="script style"/>

    <xsl:template match="/menus">
<html>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
    <head>
        <title>Portal</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//
// Show hide language block
//
function lang(s) {
    var elD = document.getElementById('german');
    var elE = document.getElementById('english');
    if(elD && elE) {    /// <<---- error occurs here
        elD.style.display = s == 'german' ? 'block': 'none';
        elE.style.display = s == 'german' ? 'none': 'block';
    }
}
        </script>
</head>
</xsl:text> 
<body>
    <h2>Das Portal ist vorübergehend unerreichbar / The Portal is temporarily unavailable</h2>

    <div><a href="#" onclick="lang('german')">deutsch</a> | <a href="#"  onclick="lang('english')">English</a>
    </div>

    <div id="german">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//menu[@lang='de']"/>
    </div>

    <div id="english">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//menu[@lang='en']"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting your script in a CDATA section.  AFAIK a CDATA section in your XSLT file will not translate to a CDATA section in your output file.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <![CDATA[
// 
// Show hide language block 
// 
function lang(s) { 
    var elD = document.getElementById('german'); 
    var elE = document.getElementById('english'); 
    if(elD && elE) {    /// <<---- error occurs here 
        elD.style.display = s == 'german' ? 'block': 'none'; 
        elE.style.display = s == 'german' ? 'none': 'block'; 
    } 
} 
  ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: @Paul: Have you used this suggestion and removed the superflous xsl:text element?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones yes. Still same error. I'll make a simplified example and try it again. Perhaps something else is triggering the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try it as character entities: `if(elD &amp;&amp; elE)` and move the `<xsl:text>` tags inside `<script>`.

Comment: did that. Just got carried straight through to the output so JS threw an error instead. I'm currently using the pragmatic approach -- if(elD) if(elE) { .... :-)

Comment: .Net seems to be the odd one out. libxslt, Saxon, Xalan-J and Sablotron spit out "&&".

Comment: 'odd one out' or 'feature' or 'bug'?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time an MS technology differed from the standard, but I haven't looked at them closely enough to tell.

Answer (score 0):

For Information I succeed to:

- import external javascript in the HEAD part
- define my own javascript in the body

For a reason I still ignore, the xsl:text is needed otherwise it is impossible to import an external javascript.

```
        <html>
        <xsl:text  disable-output-escaping="yes">
        <![CDATA[
        <head>
            <title>Products - Eshop</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./catalog.css"/>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.condense.js"></script>
        </head>
        ]]>
        </xsl:text>   
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript">  
                <![CDATA[
                $(document).ready(function(){
                
                     $('.condensed').condense({    
                        moreSpeed: 'fast',
                        lessSpeed: 'slow',
                        moreText: 'show more',
                        lessText: 'show less',
                        ellipsis: " [more...]",
                        condensedLength: 40
                });                                     
                });
                ]]>
            </script>
            
            <h3>List of Accessories</h3>

                            ... AND SO ON ...
```